# Android custom listview layout

Tags: android, listview

im new to android and java programming. Im having trouble getting my custom layout (currently with only one textview in it to work with my code. I have followed many tutorials and look and many examples but still Im getting confused as to how I would integrate it with my existing code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class checkListActivity extends MainActivity {
static String filename = "checkList";
String currentList;
SharedPreferences checkListData;
SharedPreferences.Editor checkListEditor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checklist);
    Button bAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddItem);
    final EditText etItemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etItemName);
    final TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    final ListView lvCheckList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCheckLists);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String selectedItem = extras.getString("selectedItem");
        // get the value based on the key
        currentList = selectedItem;
    }

    tvTitle.setText(currentList);

    checkListData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    updateListView();

    // Button Click Listener
    bAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String checkListStringData = etItemName.getText().toString();
            checkListData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor checkListEditor = checkListData.edit();
            checkListEditor.putString(currentList + "ItemName",
                    checkListStringData);
            checkListEditor.commit();

            String checkListDataReturned = checkListData.getString(
                    currentList + "ItemName", currentList);
            tvTitle.setText(checkListDataReturned);

            updateListView();
            etItemName.setText("");
        };
    });
}

private void updateListView() {
    final ListView lvCheckList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCheckList);
    Map<String, ?> keys = checkListData.getAll();

    ArrayList<String> checkListStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals(currentList + "ItemName")) {
                checkListStrings.add((String) entry.getValue());
            }
        }   
                ArrayAdapter<String> checkListArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.single_listview_item);
                lvCheckList.setAdapter(checkListArrayAdapter);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: For a better response, describe what happens when you try to run this, and post the error your getting from Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

first create this custom adapter class...

```
private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;
     public Context con;
     public String[] sms;
     public EfficientAdapter(Context context,String[] rssFeed) {
     mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     this.con=context;
     this.sms=rssFeed;
     }

     public int getCount() {
     return sms.length;
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
         return sms[position];
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
     return position;
     }

     @SuppressLint({ "SdCardPath", "InflateParams", "ResourceAsColor" })
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     final ViewHolder holder;
     if (convertView == null) {
     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
     holder = new ViewHolder();

     holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_list_f);

     convertView.setTag(holder);
     } else {
     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }

     holder.text2.setText(sms[position]);


     }


     return convertView;

     }
     }
     static class ViewHolder {
     TextView text2;

     }
```

then use it in your activity ...

```
list.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this, your array));
```